# Extracting all words and clusters of letters in a string and then making each word a seperate piece of data using gsub() in R

Tags: r, extract, gsub

Say we have:

```
stringTest <- c("Here we have 4 words", "Here we have avwerfaf 4")
```

Expected output:

"Here"  "we"  "have"  "words"  "Here"  "we"  "have"  "avwerfaf"

I would like to use gsub(), but other methods are definitely excepted. Thanks Guys!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `strsplit`:

```r
result <- unlist(strsplit(stringTest, " |\\d"))
result[result != ""]
#> [1] "Here"     "we"       "have"     "words"    "Here"     "we"      
#> [7] "have"     "avwerfaf"
```

or if you prefer a one-liner:

```
unlist(lapply(strsplit(stringTest, "\\W|\\d"), function(x) x[x != ""]))
```

Comment: Is there anyway to get the spaces out

Comment: @HunterThomas there are no spaces. There is a vector of 8 character strings, none of which have spaces, just like you show in your desired output

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)

stringTest <- c("Here we have 4 words", "Here we have avwerfaf 4")

gsub(" \\d", replacement = "", stringTest) %>%
  str_split(pattern = " ") %>%
  unlist()
```

Answer (score 0):

This falls under the "another approach" category. What you appear to be doing is tokenizing by words, dropping numbers.

```r
library(tokenizers)

unlist(tokenize_words(stringTest, lowercase = FALSE, strip_numeric = TRUE))
```

Which gives:

```r
[1] "Here"     "we"       "have"     "words"    "Here"     "we"       "have"     "avwerfaf"
```

---

If you are operating out of a data frame, something like this could be useful.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidytext)

df <- tibble(description = stringTest)

df2 <- df %>% 
  rowid_to_column() %>% 
  unnest_tokens(word, description, to_lower = FALSE, strip_numeric = TRUE)
```

Which returns a new tibble:

```r
> df2
# A tibble: 8 x 2
  rowid word    
  <int> <chr>   
1     1 Here    
2     1 we      
3     1 have    
4     1 words   
5     2 Here    
6     2 we      
7     2 have    
8     2 avwerfaf
```

Comment: I have a tibble with a  lot of descriptions and I am trying to extract all the words into another tibble where each word has its own row. Is this possible?

Comment: Added something for that case. Somewhat off topic from your original question though.